# Add Authorization & Origin headers to traefik reverse proxy

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

I have a very simple setup with with Traefik using Docker & Let's Encrypt to proxy incoming requests to an API service.

All is up and running well except that client's can't make requests to the API because of CORS.

**How can I add Origin, Content-Type, and Authorization headers so I can ensure they reach my Node API running behind the proxy and ensure Access-Control-Allow-Origin are kept in the response headers?**

My traefik.toml file:

```
        debug = false

        logLevel = "ERROR"
        defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

        [entryPoints]
        [entryPoints.http]
        address = ":80"
            [entryPoints.http.redirect]
            entryPoint = "https"
        [entryPoints.https]
        address = ":443"
        [entryPoints.https.tls]

        [retry]

        [docker]
        endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
        domain = "<hostname-here>"
        watch = true
        exposedByDefault = false

        [acme]
        email = "<your-email-here>"
        storage = "acme.json"
        entryPoint = "https"
        onHostRule = true
        [acme.httpChallenge]
        entryPoint = "http"
```

My `docker-compose.yml` that runs my API:

```
version: "2"
services:

  app: 
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-App
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
    restart: always
    networks:
      - web
      - default
    expose:
      - "5000"
    labels:
      - "traefik.docker.network=web"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.basic.frontend.rule=Host:${HOSTNAME}"
      - "traefik.frontend.auth.forward.trustForwardHeader=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.passHostHeader=true"
      - "traefik.basic.port=5000"
      - "traefik.basic.protocol=http"

networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

The docs imply you can add customHeaders

> traefik.frontend.headers.customResponseHeaders=EXPR    Appends the headers to each response returned by the container, before forwarding the response to the client.
>   Format: HEADER:value||HEADER2:value2

But how am I supposed to know the value of dynamic values such as Authorization Tokens?

EDIT:

I tried adding a custom header like this:

`- "traefik.frontend.headers.customResponseHeaders=Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"`

But that's not being appended to the response headers at all.

Answer (score 0):

entrypoint > Router > Middleware > Service

I think you should create the middleware first then attach it to the specific router:
I got the headers added to the response by adding these labels to my service :

```
        ...
        - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.entrypoints=http"
#creating middleware for headers
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.frontend.headers.customresponseheaders.Access-Control-Allow-Methods=POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.frontend.headers.customresponseheaders.Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.frontend.headers.customresponseheaders.Access-Control-Allow-Headers=x-requested-with, Content-Type,Authorization"
#attach middleware to the frontend router
        - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.middlewares=frontend"
```

Answer (score -1):

I was conditionally resolving CORS in my nodejs  application based on the Origin of the request in an effort to white-list host names, but the origin wasn't being set by Traefik properly. I removed the conditional and white-listed host names with Traefik instead.

After doing this, CORS works properly and my labels above are sound.

Comment: potentially related (in v2): https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/5567